# Ordered Black mulberry, got a star like flowering plant

Tags: trees, fruit-trees, mulberry

I ordered Black Pakistan mulberry plant, but got this. This doesn't look like mulberry. I saw many mulberry trees and plants. What is this?
[image]

Comment: An attractive tropical, but mulberry is toothed and less glossy, isn't it? I'd contact the seller and ask for a shipment of what I ordered or a refund.